# Configure service to use WS Security in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, wsse

I'd like to configure my SOAP service to authorize it via WS security and process frames with only Username and Password in header section. Default configuration forces me to use header like this:

```
<wsse:Security>
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>scott</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>Dupa.8</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>5uW4ABku/m6/S5rnE+L7vg==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2002-08-19T00:44:02Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

I want use only:

```
<wsse:Security>
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>scott</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password>Dupa.8</wsse:Password>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

How could I achieve it? Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get what I need. Instead of use WS security itself I choose to made custom SoapHeader. Here is my code:

Custom SoapHeader class:

```
public class UsernameToken
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Security", Namespace = "wsse", IsNullable = false)]
public class Security : SoapHeader
{
    public UsernameToken UsernameToken;
}
```

Adding this header to WebService:

```
public Security header;
[WebMethod]
[SoapHeader("header", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.In)]
/* Here is code of my method */
```

And now everything works as I want. I hope this code could help someone else.